# Image in Verticle Menu not Aligning to Menu Container

Tags: html, css, image, html-lists, center

So I can't get an image that is in the  tags to align in the center of the main wrapper/Ul. I've tried adding class to the image in the tag , the  tag itself, and the  tag, but no matter if I use position or float the image remains just slightly out of the menu wrapper. It's been a few years since I've this, so I must be forgetting a basic step here to get it to work.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: gray;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

}

ul {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
}

introImg {
  float: none;
  position:inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #949494;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #A0A0A0;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #C2C2C2;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">JavaScript Menu Conversion</h1>
    <p align="center">Converting old JavaScript to menu to Static HTML & CSS.</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttontop.png">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li class= "imgNav"><a href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/introbutton.jpg"></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Story</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Prologue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch1: Serdian War</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch2: The Platinum Shadow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch3: Fate and Soul</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch4: Moon and Fate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Characters</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Game Help</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Printables</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MIDIs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MP3s</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voice Clips</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Etc.</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links In/Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voices/Lyrics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Translations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttonbottom.png">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is simply too wide (wider than fits into the `li` of the `nav`, so it forces its `li` parent to overflow, i.e. become wider.

To avoid that, add this CSS which will limit the image to the size (i.e. width) that fits into the `li` (including the padding):

```
li.imgNav img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here it is applied to the whole code:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: gray;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

}

ul {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
}

introImg {
  float: none;
  position:inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #949494;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #A0A0A0;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #C2C2C2;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
li.imgNav img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">JavaScript Menu Conversion</h1>
    <p align="center">Converting old JavaScript to menu to Static HTML & CSS.</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttontop.png" style="display: block;">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li class= "imgNav"><a href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/introbutton.jpg"></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Story</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Prologue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch1: Serdian War</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch2: The Platinum Shadow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch3: Fate and Soul</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch4: Moon and Fate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Characters</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Game Help</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Printables</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MIDIs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MP3s</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voice Clips</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Etc.</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links In/Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voices/Lyrics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Translations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttonbottom.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see how the image is to big. The wrapper and ul li are both set to the width of the image 180px. I need the image to be the same width as the menu header image 'buttontop.png' which is also 180.

I'm converting a JavaScript menu to HTML & CSS see it here:[link](https://tlod.net/) Screen shot incase JavaScript doesn't appear for you: [link](https://tlod.net/Screenshot_2021-02-10EndinesstheLandofDragoons.png)

Comment: You have 15px padding on both sides (on the `a` element), which leaves 150px for the image.

Comment: Ah and margin-left: 1px; now it works. Man I knew it was something basic I was forgetting or not checking. Thank you.

Comment: Note: `margin` is *not*  subtract anything from the `width`, that's always added outside of the box.

Comment: Well it moved the image out by a 1px. After I set it to 0 it aligned with everything.

Comment: Any idea how to remove the small gap between the buttontop (image above the menu) and the start of the menu?

Comment: yes, add `display: block` to that image (by default it's inline which leaves some space below it)

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't get it to work. Either by adding it to the <img> tag or with a class in CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163985/display-block-not-working-on-images-to-remove-gap

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 100%;` to the image that is overlapping the wrapper div.

Also introImg needs a . in front of it if its to be a Class or # if its meant for an ID.

Although I could not see the use of introImg in your HTML code?

So I have changed the introImg CSS code block to the img tag and have added width: 100%;

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: gray;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: gray;
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

}

ul {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  float: none;
  position:inherit;
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background: #949494;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}

li:hover a {
  background: #A0A0A0;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #C2C2C2;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">JavaScript Menu Conversion</h1>
    <p align="center">Converting old JavaScript to menu to Static HTML & CSS.</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttontop.png">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li class= "imgNav"><a href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/introbutton.jpg"></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Story</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Prologue</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch1: Serdian War</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch2: The Platinum Shadow</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch3: Fate and Soul</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ch4: Moon and Fate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Characters</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Main</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Game Help</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Printables</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Additions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Enemies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Special Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Media</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">MIDIs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MP3s</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voice Clips</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Etc.</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links In/Out</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Voices/Lyrics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Translations</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttonbottom.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: introImg was attempting to get the image to center itself in the container. I tried float, position, even text-align (html tag), and it never moved. Thanks for the help.