# Display: block not working on images to remove gap

Tags: html, css, image, menu, display

My vertical menu uses images and the image all have a small gap between them. It was suggested to use "display: block" to close the gap, but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure if something else in the CSS is messing with it. [See gaps here](https://tlod.net/)

NOTE: the aqua color is not permanent. Its just there to better see the gaps.

```css
/*MENU CSS START*/
h1 {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: gray;
}

#menuWrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 460px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
}

#menuSideimg {
  float: left;
}

.buttontop {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #666;
}

ul {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*subMenu Settings START*/
a.subMenu {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #222222;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 190px;
}
a:hover.subMenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c7b297;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 190px;
}
/*subMenu Settings END*/
/*Vertical Menu Image START (no hover)*/
li a.menuHover1 {
  background: url("../img/introbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover2 {
  background: url("../img/storybutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover3 {
  background: url("../img/charactersbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
li a.menuHover4 {
  background: url("../img/gamehelpbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover5 {
  background: url("../img/printablesbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover6 {
  background: url("../img/mediabutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover7 {
  background: url("../img/extrabutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
/*Vertical Menu Image END (no hover)*/

/*Vertical Menu Image START (hover)*/
li a:hover.menuHover1 {
  background: url("../img/introbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover2 {
  background: url("../img/storybutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover3 {
  background: url("../img/charactersbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
li a:hover.menuHover4 {
  background: url("../img/gamehelpbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover5 {
  background: url("../img/printablesbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover6 {
  background: url("../img/mediabutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover7 {
  background: url("../img/extrabutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
/*Vertical Menu Image END (hover)*/

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/*MENU CSS END*/

/*STYLE START*/
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#mainWrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 960px; // assume this is the default size
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.imgHeader {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 900px; // assume this is the default size
}
/*STYLE END*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tlod.net/include/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tlod.net/include/css/menu.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="Author" content="Keven">
        <meta name="Original Author" content="Bret">
        <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Endiness. A re-envisioning of the Legend of dragoon website known as thelegendofdragoon.net.">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

        <title>Endiness, the Land of Dragoons!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <header>
                <img class="imgHeader" style="display: block" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/header-bg.jpg">
            </header>
            <nav id="menuWrapper">
                <img class="bottontop" style="display: block" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttontop.png">
                    <ul id="menu">
                      <li><a  class="menuHover1" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover2" href=""><img  src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Prologue</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch1: Serdian War</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch2: The Platinum Shadow</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch3: Fate and Soul</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch4: Moon and Fate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover3" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Main</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover4" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Additions</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Enemies</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Experience</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Special Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover5" href=""><img class="menuHover5" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Additions</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Enemies</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Experience</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Special Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover6" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">MIDIs</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">MP3s</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Voice Clips</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover7" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Links In/Out</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Notes</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Voices/Lyrics</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Translations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttonbottom.png">
            </nav>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `display: block` *on the images* is the way to go (you don't have that in your code). Look at my snippet below, I only added this one rule to your code and the gaps are gone:

```
#menuWrapper img {
  display: block;
}
```

, which applies `display: block` to all images in the menu:

```css
/*MENU CSS START*/
h1 {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: gray;
}

#menuWrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 180px;
  height: 460px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
#menuWrapper img {
  display: block;
}
#menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0em;
}

#menuSideimg {
  float: left;
}

.buttontop {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 10px #666;
}

ul {
  font-family: Veranda, Ariel, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0;
}

/*subMenu Settings START*/
a.subMenu {
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #222222;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 190px;
}
a:hover.subMenu {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c7b297;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 190px;
}
/*subMenu Settings END*/
/*Vertical Menu Image START (no hover)*/
li a.menuHover1 {
  background: url("../img/introbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover2 {
  background: url("../img/storybutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover3 {
  background: url("../img/charactersbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
li a.menuHover4 {
  background: url("../img/gamehelpbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover5 {
  background: url("../img/printablesbutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover6 {
  background: url("../img/mediabutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a.menuHover7 {
  background: url("../img/extrabutton.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
/*Vertical Menu Image END (no hover)*/

/*Vertical Menu Image START (hover)*/
li a:hover.menuHover1 {
  background: url("../img/introbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover2 {
  background: url("../img/storybutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover3 {
  background: url("../img/charactersbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
li a:hover.menuHover4 {
  background: url("../img/gamehelpbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover5 {
  background: url("../img/printablesbutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover6 {
  background: url("../img/mediabutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}

li a:hover.menuHover7 {
  background: url("../img/extrabutton2.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 180px;
  height: 28px;
}
/*Vertical Menu Image END (hover)*/

li ul {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: gray;
  color: #000;
  border-top: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
}

ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/*MENU CSS END*/

/*STYLE START*/
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

#mainWrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 960px; // assume this is the default size
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.imgHeader {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 900px; // assume this is the default size
}
/*STYLE END*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tlod.net/include/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://tlod.net/include/css/menu.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="Author" content="Keven">
        <meta name="Original Author" content="Bret">
        <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Endiness. A re-envisioning of the Legend of dragoon website known as thelegendofdragoon.net.">
        <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

        <title>Endiness, the Land of Dragoons!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mainWrapper">
            <header>
                <img class="imgHeader" style="display: block" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/header-bg.jpg">
            </header>
            <nav id="menuWrapper">
                <img class="bottontop" style="display: block" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttontop.png">
                    <ul id="menu">
                      <li><a  class="menuHover1" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover2" href=""><img  src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Prologue</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch1: Serdian War</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch2: The Platinum Shadow</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch3: Fate and Soul</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Ch4: Moon and Fate</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover3" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Main</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Other</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover4" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Additions</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Enemies</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Experience</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Special Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover5" href=""><img class="menuHover5" src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Abnormalities</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Additions</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Art of Fighting</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Enemies</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Experience</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Item Locations</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Sidequests</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Special Items</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Stardust Picture Guide</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Team/Stat Evaluation</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Weapons/Armor</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Walkthrough</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover6" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">MIDIs</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">MP3s</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Videos</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Voice Clips</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/spacer.jpg">
                      <li><a class="menuHover7" href=""><img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/blank-link-img.png"></a>
                        <ul>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Links In/Out</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Notes</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Voices/Lyrics</a></li>
                          <li><a class="subMenu" href="#">Translations</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <img src="https://tlod.net/include/img/buttonbottom.png">
            </nav>
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note: Images by default are inline elements and placed on the baseline, like letters. However, letters can have "descenders", like the letters y, g, p etc., where a part of the letter goes below the baseline, so that space below the baseline is needed for letters. But of course not for images. So if your image is the only content of a container, apply `display: block` to it, so there is no baseline alignment, and therefore no empty space below the image.

Comment: Well I tried it in the <img> tag itself and than in the wrapper (though I didn't use ther 'img' part.